# Cannot access an object property in my array map?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm not able to access object's properties from my array.

Here is my code:

```
{
    this.props.viewer.messagesByUser.edges.map(edge => {
        console.log("chatFriendPopPup id = ", chatFriendPopPup.id)
        console.log("receiver['_id'] = ", edge.node.receiver['_id']) // returns undefined
        console.log("receiver._id = ", edge.node.receiver._id) // returns undefined
        console.log("receiver._id = ", edge.node.receiver)
        if (edge.node.receiver._id.toString() === chatFriendPopPup.id.toString()) {
            return <li > {
                edge.node.body
            } - seen: {
                edge.node.seen
            } < /li>
        }
    })
}
```

Receiver has properties like this, but I cannot get `._id`

```
{
    _id: 597 f7eb1e5131d5a50e18d14,
    updatedAt: 2017 - 07 - 31 T19: 02: 09.035 Z,
    createdAt: 2017 - 07 - 31 T19: 02: 09.035 Z,
    fullName: 'ria atayde',
    email: 'myloves@gmail.com',
}
```

Comment: What does `edge.node.receiver` return with `console.log()`? Are you sure it's the exact object format as you've laid it out?

Comment: Have you tried using `receiver.toObject()._id`?

Comment: You probably have a cursor, and have to convert it or do a "lean" request to db

Comment: @ChristopherMesser it returns an object but I cannot access the _id property

Comment: @AndrewLi I can't find toObject on Mdn?

Comment: @iamnewbie I was assuming `receiver` is a Mongoose document?

Comment: @AndrewLi yes. used populate on it. but it returns an error toObject is not a function